# Regular expression for validating url with parameters

Tags: regex, url

I have been searching high and low for a solution to this, but to no avail. I am trying to prevent users from entering poorly formed URLs. Currently I have this regular expression in place:

```
^(http|https)\://.*$
```

This does a check to make sure the user is using *http* or *https* in the URL. However I need to go a step further and validate the structure of the URL.

For example this URL: `http://mytest.com/?=test` is clearly invalid as the parameter is not specified. All of the regular expressions that I've found on the web return valid when I use this URL.

I've been using [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) site to test the expressions that I've been finding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Comment: i've tried this  ^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))? which is supposed to validate the structure. However when using this, even https://www.google.com fails.

Comment: Crayon - i've tried the solutions in that thread and they dont seem to work for me

Comment: well then your issue is somewhere else, because the patterns in that thread work fine

Comment: On what URLs is this failing, exactly?  What is the string element that is not correctly matching?

Comment: the above expression fails  http://mytest.com/?=test but also fails https://www.google.com so clearly something isnt right

Comment: also the http and www. was stripped from my last comment. i'm using this site:

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look I think the best solution for testing the URL as :

```
 var url="http://mytest.com/?=test";
```

Make 2 steps :

1- test only URL as :
`http://mytest.com/` 
use pattern :

```
var pattern1= "^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)([A-Za-z]){2,3}(\/)?";
```

2- split URL string by using `pattern1` to get the URL query string and IF URL has Query string then make test on It again by using the following pattern :

```
var query=url.split(pattern1);
var q_str = query[1];
var pattern2 = "^(\?)?([0-9A-Za-z]+=[0-9A-Za-z]+(\&)?)+$";
```

Good Luck,

Comment: Hey Ahmed thanks for the reply. i hear what you are saying, however i dont have the option of having the 2 step solution. you see my page is rendered from xml which is stored in a database, this xml contains the regex expression - if you see what i mean? i may have to ditch the validation altogether tbh.

Comment: i will try and use two validators. i'll let you know how it goes

Comment: btw the xml parser is not happy about pattern2. it's complaining about the '&' is there another alternative?

Comment: just tried it and it didnt work unfortunately. still says the url is invalid even if its a simple one such as google.co.uk

Comment: ok try that pattern `var pattern = "^((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www.)?)?([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)([A-Za-z]){2,3}(\/)?([0-9A-Za-z]*(\.|\-)*[0-9A-Za-z]*(\/)?)?(\?)?([0-9A-Za-z]+=[0-9A-Za-z]+(\&)?)*$";`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having comes from the fact that what is or is not a valid parameter from a query string is not universally defined. And specifically for your problem, the criteria for a valid query is still not well defined from your single example of what should fail.

To be precise, check this out [RFC3986#3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4)

Maybe you can make up a criteria for what should be an "acceptable" query string and from that you can get an answer. ;)